# How to write several lines in TeX without line feed?

Tags: tex-core, line-spacing

How to write several lines in TeX/LaTeX without line feed? The lines should not lie vertically on top of each other, but the result should be similar to what you get when you type a line with your typewriter and then move carriage back to the right and then type the next line without a line feed, so that the letters of the second line overwrite the letters of the first line. You should be able to put a frame around what you get—like a `\fbox`, so that the frame is vertically separated both at the top from the highest character  and at the bottom  from the deepest character by `\fboxsep`.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

You can simply set `\baselineskip` to 0pt

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep} {%
      \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen\baselineskip=0pt\relax
      How to write several lines in
      TeX/LaTeX without line feed? The lines should not lie vertically
      on top of each other, but the result should be similar to what
      you get when you type a line with your typewriter and then move
      carriage back to the right and then type the next line without a
      line feed, so that the letters of the second line overwrite the
      letters of the first line. You should be able to put a frame
      around what you get—like a \texttt{\string\fbox}, so that the
      frame is vertically separated both at the top from the highest
      character and at the bottom from the deepest character by
      \texttt{\string\fboxsep}.}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use `\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}` just before the `\fbox` if you want no padding in the box.

Comment: `\baselineskip=0pt \relax` because the text can begin with the "Plus" word, not by "How". Or exchange settings of `\lineskiplimit` and `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @wipet well of course I should have used `\setlength` :-) but OK I'll add, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd just set the separate lines inside a `tabular` with a frame around the same cell. Overwriting lines is achieve with a negative line break `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`.

[image: 1]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l |}
  \hline
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
  Vestibulum sit amet velit vel elit tincidunt placerat. \\
  Mauris sit amet magna venenatis, malesuada magna eget, venenatis ex. \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{| l |}
  \hline
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  Vestibulum sit amet velit vel elit tincidunt placerat. \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
  Mauris sit amet magna venenatis, malesuada magna eget, venenatis ex. \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```